# Move command takes to long to be processed Windows?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, file-transfer

In Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium when I issue a move command from a partition of the HDD to the last partition of the same HDD it takes too long to process. Before the actual procedure commences the message `calculating` is displayed for a pretty long time. I am not exactly sure if this is only pertinent to moving data between partitions, but this happens occasionally. What may be the cause, is it an alarm for HDD health?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'Calculating' message is a normal one and is always shown (sometimes too fast for us to see), and might take longer depending on the quantity of files you want to transfer (doesn't matter if you want to copy or to move).

AFAIK it calculates the size of all files and checks that there's enough free space on the destination.
If there are many files (even small ones) it takes longer because it requires more seek operations for each file.
The same applies for other HDD-related operations.

Comment: Thanks for the through answer, I think it is reasonable.